# How to change default gradle version for flutter projects

Tags: flutter

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlinkotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

I know that I can change the `gradle:4.1.0` to the required gradle version
and then change the `distributionUrl` present in the `gradle-wrapper.properties`. But every time I create a new project I get the the same old version 4.1.0 and then I have to manually change it again. How can I set a default version for it?

Comment: Try this  additional step of upgrading my compileSdkVersion 28 to compileSdkVersion 31

Comment: From where can we do that?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -2):

Go to `app/build.gradel`
add this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just let me know if its helpful or not  because if its not I will delete this post since it is not relevent to the question.

Comment: This is just ans to your comment , to make you understand more clearly

Comment: Your answer only changes the Android SDK versions which does not answer the OP's question. If that relates to the Kotlin version, you should explain how.